# View getting null when inside FireStore collection Android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, nullpointerexception

I am making a multiplayer game for Android and creating multiplayer game rooms. But there is a strange situation which I didn't solve. When I click the button to create a multiplayer room first, it can be created, but when I return to the back fragment and want to create again my app crashes.

```
class SeviyeBirFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var db : FirebaseFirestore
    lateinit var db2 : FirebaseFirestore
    lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth
    
    val roomsList = arrayListOf<String>()
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        val view : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_seviye_bir, container, false)
        
        return view
    }
    

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db2 = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        

   
            createGame.setOnClickListener {

                startingTheGame()

            }
        

    }
    

    private fun startingTheGame() {
        

        createRoomButton.setOnClickListener {


            createRoomButton.text = "Game is Creating..."
            createRoomButton.isEnabled = false

            playerName = mAuth.currentUser?.displayName.toString()

            roomName = playerName

            val hashMap = hashMapOf<Any,Any>()
            if (roomName != null) {
                hashMap.put("player1",roomName)
            }

            db.collection("Rooms").add(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener {

                Toast.makeText(context,"Successful!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                roomListener()

            }

        }



        listView.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
            

            roomName = roomsList.get(i)


            println("roomlist a: " + roomsList.get(i) )

            println("roomlist a: " + roomName )

            val hashMap2 = hashMapOf<Any,Any>()
            if (roomName != null) {
                hashMap2.put("player2",roomName)
            }


            db.collection("Rooms").add(hashMap2).addOnSuccessListener {

                Toast.makeText(context,"Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                roomListener()

            }

        }

        addRoomsEventListener()




    }

    private fun roomListener() {

        db.collection("Rooms").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->

            if (error != null) {

                createRoomButton.setText("Create Game")
                createRoomButton.isEnabled = true

                Toast.makeText(context,"İnternet Sıkıntısı!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            } else {

                createRoomButton.setText("Create Game")
                createRoomButton.isEnabled = true

                val intent = Intent(activity,Main2Activity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                requireActivity().finish()

            }

        }
    }

    private fun addRoomsEventListener() {

        db2.collection("Rooms")

        db2.collection("Rooms").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->


            if (error == null) {

                if (value != null){

                    if (!value.isEmpty){

                        val documents = value.documents

                        for ( document in documents) {

                            val deger = document.getString("player1")
                            val deger2 = document.getString("player2")

                            if (deger != null) {
                                roomsList.add(deger)

                                if (deger2 != null) {
                                    roomsList.add(deger2)

                                }
                            }

                            val arrayAdapter : ArrayAdapter<String>? =
                                context?.let { ArrayAdapter(it,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,roomsList) }

                            println("roomlist: " + roomsList)
                            listView.adapter = arrayAdapter

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }




    }
    

}
```

In this code when clicking the createRoomButton, my room was created first but when return back and click again app crashes. I checked the button from XML it is no problem for findViewById.

It gives this error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.Adapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference.

it refers to listView.Adapter = adapter

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Please share the code where you are using .setAdapter().

Comment: I already shared, it is on addRoomsEventListener()

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem. Maybe any person can encounter this error thats why I will explain the solution. Actually, I have never noticed that firestore listeners continues while switching between fragments or activities. First of all, i initialize the references like that ;

```
var reference: ListenerRegistration? = null
var reference2: ListenerRegistration? = null
```

After that I equalize the listeners ;

```
reference = db.collection("Rooms").addSnapshotListener {...} 
reference2 = db2.collection("Rooms").addSnapshotListener {...}
```

And Finally, I remove these references when I change my fragment or destroy my activity.

```
  override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()

     reference?.remove()
     reference2?.remove()

}
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with your actual question. The NullPointerException that is referring to `listView.Adapter = adapter`, clearly indicates that your `listView` object is null.